# How can I add multiple modals to a site?

Tags: forms, ajax, chaos-tool-suite

Of course there are many ways to add modals, I've been sandboxing a lightweight method leveraging ctools; but how would I add several distinct modals to a site? I have thought about making a modal content type, which could then have many instances, but I'm not able to imagine how to get node content in modals in a way that I could then use contexts to show them in various parts of the site. I'm wondering if the community has any insights here.

Comment: I don't really understand the question.. You want modal pop ups showing node content? What do you mean by "distinct"?

Comment: By distinct I mean different modals (forms) showing depending on context.